# Combos anidados jQuery, el combo hijo no actualiza su contenido cuando se produce onChange

Tags: html, jquery, rest

Tengo dos combos anidados, el segundo depende el valor del primero, muevo los datos con un script REST (los datos de ambos combos los obtengo en JSON, sin embargo para ponerlo aquí pongo los valores del primero a mano). Necesito propagar una variable de una función click de jQuery afuera de la misma función.

Aquí el formulario:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
  <select class="form-control" id="selecttarea" name="id_tarea"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>               
  <select class="form-control" id="selectcliente" name="id_cliente"></select>
</form>
```

Hasta ahora estoy usando localStorage para ello y me funciona bien la primera vez que selecciono una opción, pero al seleccionar de nuevo, me conserva el valor anterior en el segundo combo aunque envio IDs diferentes. He probado a poner un remove local storage pero no me funciona bien.

A continuación el script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("#selecttarea").change(function(){
                var identificadortarea = $('select[id=selecttarea]').val();
                localStorage.setItem("identificadortr",identificadortarea);
                apppcl.readPostsH();
                $(document).bind('deviceready', apppcl.onDeviceReady); 
        }); 
    });
    var identificacion_emplead = sessionStorage.getItem("identificador");//lo tengo almacenado en sesion
    var dortarea = localStorage.getItem("identificadortr");
    var apppcl = {
        posts_urlcl: "http://www.url.com/listas.json.php?id_empleado="+identificacion_emplead+"&id_tarea="+dortarea,
        onDeviceReady: function() {
            apppcl.readPostsH();
        },
        readPostsH: function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: apppcl.posts_urlcl,
                success: apppcl.onSuccess

            });
        },
        onSuccess: function(datoscl) {
            var selectcliente = [];
            $.each(datoscl, function(key, val){
                if(val.empresa==''){
                    selectcliente.push('<option value="' + val.id_cliente + '"> ' + val.nombre + ' ' + val.apellido1 + ' ' + val.apellido2 + '</option>');
                } else {
                    selectcliente.push('<option value="' + val.id_cliente + '"> ' + val.empresa + '</option>'); 
                }
            });
            $('#selectcliente').html(selectcliente.join('<br/>'));
        },
    };
```

Cómo puedo reiniciar el combo dos cada vez que se produce el onChange? hay una solución mejor que la de usar el localStorage?

Answer (score 0):

puede ser por que se esta quedando la información en el select intenta limpindo el contenido html con $('#selectcliente').html("")

ejemplo:

```
onSuccess: function(datoscl) {
            var selectcliente = [];
            $('#selectcliente').html("");
            $.each(datoscl, function(key, val){
                if(val.empresa==''){
                    selectcliente.push('<option value="' + val.id_cliente + '"> ' + val.nombre + ' ' + val.apellido1 + ' ' + val.apellido2 + '</option>');
                } else {
                    selectcliente.push('<option value="' + val.id_cliente + '"> ' + val.empresa + '</option>'); 
                }
            });
            $('#selectcliente').html(selectcliente.join('<br/>'));
        },
```

Comment: No me funciona, sigue cargando el valor de localStorage, opino que debería borrar la variable local, pero tampoco me funciona así